# Nested Shell View in prism for UWP

Tags: uwp, prism, uwp-xaml, nested-views

Can a shell view be implemented as a content of a parent shell view in UWP app using prism.unity? Or is there an alternative to achieve nested shell functionality using prism in UWP?

Comment: Do you mean a shell to use a HamburgerMenu or 2 levels of navigation? We need more info.

Comment: Yes, a shell with 2 levels of navigation. The parent shell will have its own navigation for content inside it and the child shell will have its own navigation.

Comment: Currently not possible in Prism. We're not sure if we'll add this in v7 either as this would require handling 2 backstacks.

Comment: Thank you Bart. Can we expect Regions(like IRegionManager in WPF) concept to be added in Prism for UWP?

Comment: Is there any alternative to achieve this kind of behavior using PRISM?